# sklearn - sample from GaussianMixture without fitting

Tags: random, scikit-learn, gmm

I would like to use a GaussianMixture for generating random data.
The parameters should not be learnt from data but supplied.

GaussianMixture allows supplying inital values for weights, means, precisions, but calling "sample" is still not possible.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
d = 10
k = 2
_weights = np.random.gamma(shape=1, scale=1, size=k)
data_gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=k, 
                           weights_init=_weights / _weights.sum(),
                           means_init=np.random.random((k, d)) * 10,
                           precisions_init=[np.diag(np.random.random(d)) for _ in range(k)])
data_gmm.sample(100)
```

This throws:

```
NotFittedError: This GaussianMixture instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

I've tried:

- Calling `_initialize_parameters()` - this requires also supplying a data matrix, and does not initialize a `covariances` variable needed for sampling.
- Calling `set_params()` - this does not allow supplying values for the attributes used by sampling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set all the attributes manually so you don't have to fit the `GaussianMixture`.

You need to set `weights_`, `means_`, `covariances_` as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
d = 10
k = 2
_weights = np.random.gamma(shape=1, scale=1, size=k)
data_gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=k)
data_gmm.weights_ = _weights / _weights.sum()
data_gmm.means_ = np.random.random((k, d)) * 10
data_gmm.covariances_ = [np.diag(np.random.random(d)) for _ in range(k)]
data_gmm.sample(100)
```

**NOTE**: You might need to modify theses parameters values according to your usecase.

Comment: Is this the most elegant way? I would think sklearn does not require me to know which internal variables should be overridden.

Comment: Well It is the only way to use scikit-learn's `GaussianMixture` without having to fit it.